# Numba CUDA shared memory size at runtime?

Tags: python, cuda, numba, gpu-shared-memory

In CUDA C++ it's straightforward to define a shared memory of size specified at runtime. How can I do this with Numba/NumbaPro CUDA?

What I've done so far has only resulted in errors with the message

```
Argument 'shape' must be a constant
```

EDIT: Just to clarify, what I want is an equivalent to the following in CUDA C++ (example taken and adapted from [here](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/):

```cpp
__global__ void dynamicReverse(int *d, int n)
{
  extern __shared__ int s[];
      
  // some work in the kernel with the shared memory
}
    
int main(void)
{
  const int n = 64;
  int a[n];
    
  // run dynamic shared memory version
  dynamicReverse<<<1,n,n*sizeof(int)>>>(a, n);

}
```

Comment: You should probably ask continuum analytics about this (it is their product), but my guess is that they don't support it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution (through the very helpful Continuum Analytics user support). What we do is define the shared memory as we'd normally do but set the shape to 0. Then, to define the size of the shared array we have to give it as the fourth parameter (after the stream identifier) to the kernel. E.g.:

```
@cuda.autojit
def myKernel(a):
   sm = cuda.shared.array(shape=0,dtype=numba.int32)

   # do stuff

arga = np.arange(512)
grid = 1
block = 512
stream = 0
sm_size = arga.size * arga.dtype.itemsize
myKernel[grid,block,stream,sm_size](arga)
```

Comment: can you create this way 2 shared memory arrays with different size ?

Comment: You should be able to create as many as you want.

Comment: You can, but ["all dynamic shared memory arrays alias, so if you want to have multiple dynamic shared arrays, you need to take disjoint views of the arrays."](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cuda/memory.html#dynamic-shared-memory)